# Logo looks great on all browsers except firefox! Need CSS advice

Tags: firefox

http://mapleleafmarkets.com/ is the website. I was assigned this from another dev who couldnt figure it out... it has me scratching my head too.

i have tested this on ie chrome and safari but mozilla seems to not play with absolute positioning the same way the others do. Any one have a clue?

thanks!

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to fix this using a nice mozilla CSS hack

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .navbar {
    margin-left: -550px !important;
  }
}
```